# iOS Core Data NSFetchedResultController.fetchedObject returns fault data and (0,0) annotation

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mapkit, nsfetchedresultscontroller

The problem is I try to retrieve saved data from core data store but got "fault-data" or not sure what is this, since I am sure I saved data correctly(valid location coordinates)
My code in view controller:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {}
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        //fetch all pins from core data and load
        let pins = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as! [Pin]
        mapView.addAnnotations(pins)
        print(pins.count)  /// 10
        print(pins)
        print(pins[0].coordinate)
        print(pins[1].coordinate)
}
```

I am sure I save each object successfully each time. 
I print out some facts: 
pins.count has some number. However, this is odd from the rest print
I got `"data: <fault>"` and zeroed location.

---

```
Pin: 0x7fdc0b40e160> (entity: Pin; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://50885CE6-70AB-4AA5-AA84-19D895E4F062/Pin/p2> ; data: <fault>)])
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not an error when you get <fault> in core data. It's feature of core data data handling. Core Data is has implemented optimized way in it to keep its memory footprint low without sacrificing performance. Faulting technique helps to achieve that. It only loads data to memory when needed. You got error due to either of following reason:

1) It's probably, you have made an error while you saved your data.

2) Logical error in managing relationship properties (optional and mandatory) of core data.

3) The core-data couldn't fulfil fault (i.e. load data from persistent store). (this could be due to number (2) logical error also). Even though core-data doesn't throw an exception after fault couldn't be fulfilled because it is managed to do so by default. You get zeros in all properties of the managed object of an inaccessible managed object.

Visit http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-a-core-data-fault--cms-25157 for more information about fault. You might get idea about fault there and possibly why you got that error.